# what does it mean to @ other functions on top of 'def' in Python?

Tags: python, function-definition

I am new to python so excuse me if this is a silly question.

I came across python code that has @other_functions right on top of def new_function() statements. Could someone please explain the meaning to it?

As in this example:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["post"])
def my_new_function(request):
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: If I add [tag:decorator] do I spoil the answer?

Comment: those are decorators, a concept a little too important to cover in a comment. but this link is a good start: https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast and helpful response! I am reading about python decorators now